# opencv and imwrite

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write frame on my disk:

.......

```
cv::Mat frame,frame32f;
char filename[40];
cv::Mat mean;
const int count =134;
const int width  = 1920;
const int height = 1080;
cv::Mat resultframe = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat deviationframe = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat deviationframe2write = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
for(int i = 1 ; i<= count; i++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",i);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3 );
    resultframe +=frame32f;
    frame.release();
}
resultframe *= (1.0/count);
for(int j =1; j<count; j++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",j);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    temp =(frame32f - resultframe);
    deviationframe+= temp.mul(temp);

    //temp.release();
}
deviationframe *= 1.0/(count -1);
deviationframe2write +=deviationframe;
cv::sqrt(deviationframe2write,deviationframe2write);
deviationframe= deviationframe/255;
cv::sqrt(deviationframe,deviationframe);
cv::imwrite("mean.tif",resultframe);
cv::imwrite("stdDev.tif",deviationframe2write);
resultframe *= 1.0/255.0;
imshow("mean ",resultframe);


imshow("deviation frame ",deviationframe);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

as you see I write the mean before multiplying it with 255 but with the `deviationframe` this just doesn't work it mean that I do save the `deviationframe2write` but when I open it it just black  any idea what I'm missing here ?? thanks in advance

Comment: That code does not make sense, at all. You seem to have three different frames that you do random stuff to. What is it that does not work? You divide `deviationframe` but never write this. You write out `resultframe` to a file and modify the frame afterwards. All of this is a big chuck of confusing spaghetti logic.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? You get invalid or unexpected values? What are the types of the variables in question?

Comment: I just edited the question with the complete code

Comment: Why are you dividing the `deviationframe` by 255 before taking sqrt and showing it, but skipping this step for `deviationframe2write` ?

Comment: to show correctly in imshow() that's why I need deviationframe2write

Comment: Why would showing it require the division, while writing it would not require it?!

Comment: that the way it works in opencv cv you can test it the other way it wouldn't work